# Sencha extjs Framework giving 500.19 on IIS 7

Tags: extjs, iis-7, extjs4

i get the following error when I configure the extjs (Sencha) framework in IIS 7.  I have Anonymous and Windows authentication enabled.  I've tried without either.  And I've also tried just anonymous.  What could be the issue?

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Requested URL   http://localhost:80/index.html
Physical Path
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to give permission to the root folder to the user group IIS_IUSRS.

Comment: NOTE: this is the answer on Windows 7.  One Windows Server 2008, you must give access to user IUSR, not IIS_IUSRS since IUSR isn't in that user group by default on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I added permissions for USERS , Authenticated Users and Network Service.
and it solved the problem.

Comment: Interesting..  I think on Windows Server 2008, you must use user IUSR, since IUSR isn't in the group IIS_IUSRS by default like it is for Windows 7.  Did you build USERS?  Or was IUSR in the group USERS by default?  What OS did you use?